# Exception with Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am getting exception while querying cassandra using Spring-Data-Cassandra . Please help
2021-06-01 12:09:48.594  INFO 9568 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.demo2.Controller.DemoController      : Error : org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [select * from summary_data where proj_id = ? and category = ? and name = ? and time >= ?]; Query timed out after PT10S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT10S

```
private final AsyncCassandraOperations asyncCassandraTemplate;

public List<Data1> getData(String convProjectId, List<String> stageNames,
        String eventCategory, List<String> distinctDateHour) {
    final String cql = "select * from summary_data where proj_id = ? and category = ? and name = ? and time >= ?";
    List<BanEventLifecycle> bList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ListenableFuture<List<Data1>>> bFutureList = new ArrayList<>();
    distinctDateHour.forEach(dateHr-> stageNames.forEach(stageName->{
        ListenableFuture<List<Data1>> futureBData = asyncCassandraTemplate.getAsyncCqlOperations().query(cql,
                ps -> ps.bind().setString(0, projectId.toLowerCase()).setString(1,dateHr)
                        .setString(2, category.toLowerCase()).setString(3, name),
                (row, rowNum) -> Data1.getData1(row));
        bFutureList.add(futureBData);
    }));
    bFutureList.forEach(future -> {
        try {
            banList.addAll(future.get());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }
    });
    return bList;
}
```

Spring-Data-Cassandra : 3.0.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

The Java driver for Cassandra throws a `DriverTimeoutException` when it doesn't get a response back from the coordinator within the driver request timeout which is your case is 10 seconds (`PT10S`).

You need to review the Cassandra logs to determine why the coordinator didn't respond to driver's request. Either you were executing an expensive query or the cluster was overloaded at the time.

Note that you shouldn't confuse `DriverTimeoutException` with a `ReadTimeoutException` which is the error thrown by the coordinator when it hasn't received responses from the replica(s) within the read request timeout. Cheers!